# How to use global scss file with css-modules?

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

I have created file index.scss in which im importing mixins and variables and then importing it in App.tsx Problem is im also using css-modules and variables imported in App.tsx are undefined in other components. Is there a way to share index.scss globally without importing it in every single scss file?